# Problems recording long Excel formula with macro recorder

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to record a macro of my formula in Excel and it gives me a syntax error.

This is the formula:

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2="toola",B2="toola1",B2="toola2",B2="SFx200"),OR(H2="Q1",H2="Q2",H2="Q3",H2="Q4")),CONCATENATE(H2," "," ",IF(I2="p","pre","")," ","SFx","-",IF(A2="",0,A2)),IF(AND(OR(B2="toolb",B2="toolb1",B2="toolb2",B2="toolb3",B2="yoolb4",B2="toolb4",B2="toolb5",B2="toolb6",B2="toolb7",B2="toolb8",B2="toolb9",B2="toolb10",B2="toolb11",B2="toolb12"),OR(H2="Q1",H2="Q2",H2="Q3",H2="Q4")),CONCATENATE(H2," ",IF(I2="p","pre",""),"-"," ",IF(A2="",0,A2)),IF(AND(OR(B2="up",B2="up1",B2="up2",B2="up3",B2="up4",B2="up5",B2="Up6",B2="up7"),OR(H2="Q1",H2="Q2",H2="Q3",H2="Q4")),CONCATENATE(H2," ","UP","-",IF(A2="",0,A2)))))
```

I know that it is big, but why won't the macro recorder properly record it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro recorder is useless with long formulas as it overwrites some of the formula string when it adds in line continuations for the VB editor. You'll either need to edit the code yourself or shorten the formula - e.g. use things like `OR(H2={"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"})` rather than `OR(H2="Q1",H2="Q2",H2="Q3",H2="Q4")`

Also if possible replace something like this:

```
OR(B2="toolb",B2="toolb1",B2="toolb2",B2="toolb3",B2="yoolb4",B2="toolb4",B2="toolb5",B2="toolb6",B2="toolb7",B2="toolb8",B2="toolb9",B2="toolb10",B2="toolb11",B2="toolb12")
```

with this

```
LEFT(B2,5)="toolb"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than 7 times `if` excel does not want to work. Thus, you should go around it. With `Select Case`.

Or something like this, when the nested `ifs` are in a formula:
https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/if_custom.php

You can go up to as many `cases` as you need. Then simply use the custom formula.

Comment: That was only true in versions before Excel 2007.

Comment: Didn't know. Still, more than 7 ifs is really a lot in a formula and a similar workaround should be considered. Otherwise it is really tough to debug in Excel. And you get a formula similar to Goku - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCe3a.jpg

Comment: Also, there are only actually 3 levels of nesting of IF which is not a lot.

Comment: I just counted 8 ifs, not taking a look at the levels. And 8 ifs (even in only 3 levesl) seems to me a lot, I would not be happy to debug it in a formula.

Comment: But that's merely your opinion. To me, that's a simple formula to follow. And suggesting writing your own UDFs to someone who's using the macro recorder like this doesn't seem to be simplifying things in *my* opinion. ;)

Comment: Well, I usually write things, that are my opinion. And as far as someone needs/can write 8 ifs with 3 levels, I think that this person is ready to take the Excel to the next level.